# jquery append data not replace it solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, append

I have a code which is like this,

```
$(".addlink").live('click',function(){
             var id = $(this).attr("id");
             var value = $(this).prev('input').val();
        $(this).next('.linkshow').load("rurl/rurl_addlink.jsp?value="+value,
                function() {
            $(this).next('.linkshow').append($(this).html());
        }   
        );
```

but after loading I don't want to replace the data, instead I want to append it to class linkshow. Any ideas?

Comment: so you want to make a new link and not edit an existing one, i think the solution is simple but if you can show your html it could help provide you with a working answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".addlink").live('click',function(){
             var id = $(this).attr("id");
             var value = $(this).prev('input').val();
             my_link = $(this);
             $.get("rurl/rurl_addlink.jsp?value="+value,
                function(data) {
                   my_link.next('.linkshow').append(data);
                } 
              );
 });
```

Comment: sorry, there was a syntax mistake.

Comment: ok, i had forgotten how jQuery treats this in an ajax request. what about now?